# docs works but ui doesn't have routing?

Tags: swagger-net

I'm running my api as an application within a site in IIS. The site's url is "http://api.companyName.local/" and the api's url is "http://api.companyName.local/api".

I've got Swagger-Net set up enough that http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/docs/v1 returns swagger.json and appears to be correct. However no url I can think of brings up the UI. I've tried:

```
http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger
http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/
http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/ui
http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/ui/
http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/ui/index
```

all of which end up with this error:
[image: 404 swagger ui not found]
It looks like the routes are resolving to the `StaticFile` handler and not the `SwaggerUiHandler` handler.

This is the setup I'm trying to use

```
httpConfiguration.EnableSwagger( c => {
    c.SingleApiVersion( "v1", "Company Name API" );
    c.ResolveConflictingActions( apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First( ) );
    c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds( );
} ).EnableSwaggerUi( );
```

I've pulled down the github for Swagger-Net and started to dig around. I see it uses `httpConfiguration.VirtualPathRoot` in some places so I figure I should mention for my api this resolves to "/" in case that matters.

EDIT:

One interesting thing I just found is that I get different errors from these two urls

```
    http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/ui/v1
    http://api.companyName.local/api/swagger/ui/v2
```

The one that ends in v1 is getting into the SwaggerUiHandler but the one with v2 errors like it would without v2 at all. So it would seem that something in Swagger-Net is looking at the full url and ignoring it if it doesn't include the version. My api doesn't have versions so this is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! The solution is to add a TransferRequestHandler to the web.config to allow the ui pages to resolve into the api. The reason routes with v1 worked is because my api already had this attribute for routes with v1 in them.

```
<handlers>
    <add name="Swashbuckle-Swagger" verb="*" path="swagger/*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
```

This snipped was lifted from https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/57